# PCL load .ply file --- Failed to find match for field / user define point

Tags: c++, ros, pcl

I have a .ply file and the header is

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 131072
property float x
property float y
property float z
property float intensity
property uint t
property ushort reflectivity
property uchar ring
property ushort noise
property uint range
property uchar label
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
end_header
0 -0 0 7 0 0 0 384 0 0 0 0 0
...
...
```

Then I write a `C++/PCL` code as the following:

```
struct OusterPointS {
  PCL_ADD_POINT4D;
  float intensity;
  std::uint32_t t;
  std::uint16_t reflectivity;
  std::uint8_t ring;
  std::uint16_t noise;
  std::uint32_t range;
  std::uint8_t label;
  std::uint8_t red;
  std::uint8_t green;
  std::uint8_t blue;
  EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
} EIGEN_ALIGN16;

POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT(OusterPointS,
(float, x, x)(float, y, y)(float, z, z)(float, intensity, intensity)
(std::uint32_t, t, t)(std::uint16_t, reflectivity, reflectivity)
(std::uint8_t, ring, ring)(std::uint16_t, noise, noise)(std::uint32_t, range, range)(std::uint8_t, label, label)
(std::uint8_t, red, red)(std::uint8_t, green, green)(std::uint8_t, blue, blue)
)

int main() {
...
...
    pcl::PointCloud<OusterPointS>::Ptr os_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<OusterPointS>);
    pcl::io::loadPLYFile(os_path, *os_cloud)
...
...
}
```

Then I get the result

> Failed to find match for field 'red'.

> Failed to find match for field 'green.

> Failed to find match for field 'blue'.

---

It is really really wired because I can read all other fields except the RGB!

In addition, if I change the field name or type in the file(as well as the code), I can read it, but obviously, I don’t want to modify the file one by one.

Looking for your help~

You can find the code and .ply here [drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1trurNdjbY18_Xty7yjDuhrSV5ajUxt0U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: tried PCL 1.08  and PCL 1.11, no difference...